# Solution of the complex Ginzburg - Landau equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, quantum-mechanics

Can someone show that it's possible to find a solution of the kind:

$$\Phi(x,t)=R(x,t)\exp[i\Psi(x,t)]$$

of the complex Ginzburg - Landau equation:

$$\frac{\partial{\Phi}}{\partial{t}}=(1+ia)\frac{\partial^2{\Phi}}{\partial{x}^2}+\Phi-(ib-1)|\Phi|^2\Phi$$

assuming that $R(x,t)$ and $\Psi(x,t)$

are defined as real - valued functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any complex number $z$ can be written as $z = r e^{i\theta}$ where $r = |z| > 0$ and $\theta$ is real, so any solution $\Phi(x,t)$ can certainly be written that way.

Some particular solutions in this case are $\Phi \left( x,t \right) =R{{\rm e}^{i \left( \sqrt {1+{R}^{2}}x+
 \left( a \left( 1+{R}^{2} \right) -b{R}^{2} \right) t \right) }}
$

Comment: Dear @Robert lsrael, could you pls explain a little hint of how you have found this particular solution? Thank you!

Comment: It was over 7 years ago, so I don't remember what I did, but I suspect I substituted $\Phi(x,t) =  R e^{i(c_1 x + c_2 t)}$ and saw what $c_1$ and $c_2$ had to be to make it work.

Comment: Thank you very much, Prof. Robert. So you actually assumed the phase $\theta$ is a linear function in $x$ and $t$. Am i right?